# Splitting two ObservableCollections lightning fast

Tags: c#, performance, collections, extension-methods

I'm working on wiring up a bindable Map for Xamarin Forms, and I need a fast way of dividing up the `ObservableCollection`s (collection of map markers) as quickly as possible. Collections are a weak area for me, and I find myself doing too many `foreach`'s when they're not necessary.

Here's what I have now.

```
private static void MarkerSourceCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var markers = ((IEnumerable<XfxMarker>) sender).ToList();

    var comparer = new MapMarkerComparer();
    var offScreen = new List<XfxMarker>();
    var markersToAdd = markers.Where(m => _map.MapBounds.Contains(m.CenterPoint), out offScreen)
        .Except(_oldMarkers, comparer);

    var markersToRemove = _oldMarkers.Except(markers, comparer).Union(offScreen);
    _map.HandleMarkersChanged(markers, new MapMarkersChangedEventArgs(markersToAdd, markersToRemove));
    _oldMarkers = markers;
}
```

With the comparer

```
internal class MapMarkerComparer : IEqualityComparer<XfxMarker>
{
    public bool Equals(XfxMarker x, XfxMarker y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        var result = x.CenterPoint.Latitude.ToString() == y.CenterPoint.Latitude.ToString()
                     && x.CenterPoint.Longitude.ToString() == y.CenterPoint.Longitude.ToString();
        return result;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(XfxMarker obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hash = 0;
            if (obj.CenterPoint == null) return hash;
            hash = hash + 17;
            hash = hash*23 + obj.CenterPoint.Longitude.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash*23 + obj.CenterPoint.Latitude.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

And my custom `Where` extension.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> predicate, out List<T> remainder)
    {
        var leftover = new List<T>();
        var output = new List<T>();
        foreach (var item in input)
        {
            if (predicate.Invoke(item))
            {
                output.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                leftover.Add(item);
            }
        }
        remainder = leftover;
        return output;
    }
}
```

Now I'm sure there has to be a more efficient way to split these lists, but I'm just not sure what.

Comment: What do you mean "more efficient".  Is your code taking a long time to run?

Comment: @user2023861 I'm concerned that I've iterated the lists too many times, but I can't think of a way to reduce the loops further.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what it is your algorithm is supposed to be doing, but unless your looping noticeably effects performance, I wouldn't be worried about it.

Comment: The algorithm simply takes the new markers, and the old markers, and decides which ones need to be added to the map, and which ones need to be removed from the map. It also takes into consideration what part of the map is in the viewport. If there is a marker that is supposed to be added (IE: in the new but not in the old) but it's off screen, we don't add it... that's the purpose of the custom Where extension with the out param.

Answer (score 4):

### `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`

You receive a [NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs?view=netframework-4.8), wich holds interesting data about the items that got added `NewItems` and removed `OldItems` from the collection. There is also an `Action` that defines how the collection got modified. Your changed handler is implemented as a `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` handler. It doesn't take into account the information from the event `e`.

> ```
> var markers = ((IEnumerable<XfxMarker>) sender).ToList();
> ```

This means, you are checking all elements against the previously cached elements by the handler container class and manually verify which ones are added and which ones removed. Let's say `filter` is `m => _map.MapBounds.Contains(m.CenterPoint)`:

> ```
>  var markersToAdd = markers
>     .Where(m => filter(m), out offScreen).Except(_oldMarkers,comparer);
> ```

and

> ```
> var markersToRemove = _oldMarkers.Except(markers, comparer).Union(offScreen);
> ```

However, in most cases I presume the action to be `Add` or `Remove`. If this is the case, you already have the new and/or old elements. For instance, on `Add`:

```
var markersAddedInSource = e.NewItems.OfType<XfxMarker>();
var markersToAdd = markersAddedInSource.Where(filter);
var markersToRemove = markersAddedInSource.Except(markersToAdd);
```

Or using your own extension method:

```
var markersAddedInSource = e.NewItems.OfType<XfxMarker>();
var markersToAdd = markersAddedInSource.Where(filter, out var markersToRemove);
```

This saves you a couple of iterations on the source collection and allows you to only iterate on the changed elements.

---

### `MapMarkerComparer`

I don't know the type of `Latitude` and `Longitude`, but consider checking equality on their source type rather than their `ToString` outcome.

> ```
> x.CenterPoint.Latitude.ToString() == y.CenterPoint.Latitude.ToString()
> ```

In case you have issues with rounding or truncation (likely with `float` or `double`) you could round the values in the check.

```
x.CenterPoint.Latitude == y.CenterPoint.Latitude
```

Or you could use rounding:

```
Math.Round(x.CenterPoint.Latitude, precision) 
    == Math.Round(y.CenterPoint.Latitude, precision)
```

Or you could guard against a tolerance threshold:

```
Math.Abs(x.CenterPoint.Latitude - y.CenterPoint.Latitude) < tolerance
```

---

### `IEnumerable<T> Where<T>`

Consider changing the method signature to

```
public static ILookup<bool, T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> predicate);
```

Or returning a Dictionary:

```
public static IDictionary<bool, IEnumerable<T>> Where<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> predicate);
```

So you don't need to worry about a return value and an out-parameter. This pattern isn't used that much anymore and is mostly used to `Try*` operations.

You can get the items that matched the `predicate`:

```
var results = markers.Where(filter);
var matched = results[true];
var unmatched = results[false];
```

Considering renaming `Where` to avoid confusion with LINQ's `Where` method.